# Langchain - offline only

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am using langchain with a large chunk of text - journalistic info. Can i force langchain to give results of what I only have stored in data and not search in ChatGPT database? I know it needs to connect to OpenAI to read my data, but i need to force an "offline" search only.

Is there a better LLM option?

Thank you!

For my first and second time asking a question it says that there is no info, third time it connects to ChatGPT to give an answer - i need to at least know from where it is extracting the answer from.

Comment: Langchain is a project that allows you to connect to many LLMs. OpenAI's is just one of them. If you're using their LLM, it's not available offline; you'd need to pick a different model that can be run on your own servers, something like llama2.

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of LLMs from HuggingFace, which will be downloaded onto your disk, when the code is executed first time, and provide query locally (no internet required), eg. doing `similarity_search` with embedding. For example:

```py
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings

embeddings = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can load a specific file and have your llm answer based on this context. There are variety of methods to implement this. For example:

```
import os
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "your-api-key"

pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader('./your_doc.pdf')
documents = pdf_loader.load()

from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

chain = load_qa_chain(llm=OpenAI())
query = 'what is your question?'
response = chain.run(input_documents=documents, question=query)
print(response)
```

Or, Huggingface has some offline models that you download it to your machine. [This](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/installation) will guide you how to set huggingface `transformers` and models offline.

Beware that you need strong hardware to interact with the llm model offline.